# SQL Join Problems

Tags: sql, join, infinite-loop

I'm having a problem that I assume is related to the Join in my SQL statement.

```
select s.customer as 'Customer', 
    s.store as 'Store', 
    s.item as 'Item', 
    d.dlvry_dt as 'Delivery', 
    i.item_description as 'Description', 
    mj.major_class_description as 'Major Description', 
    s.last_physical_inventory_dt as 'Last Physical Date', 
    s.qty_physical as 'Physical Qty', 
    s.avg_unit_cost as 'Unit Cost', 
    [qty_physical]*[avg_unit_cost] as Value 
from argus.DELIVERY d 
join argus.STORE_INVENTORY s 
    ON (s.store = d.store)
join argus.ITEM_MASTER i 
    ON (s.item = i.item)
join argus.MINOR_ITEM_CLASS mi 
    ON (i.minor_item_class = mi.minor_item_class)
join argus.MAJOR_ITEM_CLASS mj 
    ON (mi.major_item_class = mj.major_item_class)
where s.last_physical_inventory_dt between '6/29/2011' and '7/2/2012' 
    and s.customer = '20001' 
    and s.last_physical_inventory_dt IS NOT NULL
```

It comes back with a seemingly infinite amount of copies of one record. Is there something wrong with the way I'm joining these tables?

Comment: Instead of all of the columns you are looking at, I suggest selecting `COUNT(*)` to find out how many records are actually being returned.

Comment: Wow, that returns 1623697...but it's the same record over and over!

Comment: Try to comment out one of the joins at a time

Comment: When I leave just "from argus.STORE_INVENTORY s" then it returns 34 records. As soon as I add the joins, it multiplies. EDIT: It seems like it only happens when I leave in the DELIVERY table

Comment: You should probably start with one table, join in another, etc., and really inspect the results. Presumably each of these tables has a unique identifier. As you work from one to all tables, add the unique identifiers to the SELECT list so you can see exactly what rows are being matched in the joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
join argus.MINOR_ITEM_CLASS mi 
    ON (i.minor_item_class = mi.minor_item_class)
join argus.MAJOR_ITEM_CLASS mj 
    ON (mi.major_item_class = mj.major_item_class)
```

My guess is that your error resides in one of these 2 joins. When you only use the word JOIN it assumes that you are trying to do an INNER JOIN which returns all records that have at least 1 to 1. I don't know what your data looks like but I am assuming that there is a many to many relationship between minor item class and major item class so when you run this query you are receiving duplicated records for almost every field, but the major item class differs.

I would look at the results. Most of the columns will have repeating data that doesn't change while one of the columns will have a different value for every row. That should tell you that the column with differing data for each row is the column that you should be joining differently.

Otherwise, I would say that your query is formatted correctly.

Comment: I think this is the problem actually! Everything is identical on the entire thing except the DELIVERY one. Should I use a different join?

Comment: `inner join` is the most restrictive join, so this is no explanation for an unexpectedly large set

Comment: If delivery is the column that has a differing value then it is because you are joining the store table to the delivery table on something that is not a unique key. There is a many to many relationship causing your deliveries to map to many stores or vice versa. Is their a foreign key 1-to-1 relationship that you could join with instead?

Comment: This was exactly the problem. I was joining on something that wasn't unique and it was duplicating every record 100s of times. Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Good luck moving forward with your work